# Windows 8 Task Manager without elevating?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, task-manager, elevation

In Windows Vista and Windows 7, the task manager ran non-elevated, and you didn't face a UAC prompt unless you chose "View Processes of All Users".

In Windows 8 Preview, out of the box the Task Manager starts elevated every time.  **How can I configure it to start non-elevated** so I don't get hit with a UAC prompt every time I check CPU usage or view the list of running processes to see if an application closed completely?

(I am not looking for answers which involve weakening UAC, and I ask the community's help in downvoting any such suggestions.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Compatibility "shims" can be used to override the manifest; you can start Task Manager with the `__compat_layer` environment variable set to `runasinvoker`, e.g. from a command prompt:
`set __compat_layer=runasinvoker

taskmgr`

Or, use [Compatibility Administrator](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825182.aspx) to apply the "RunAsInvoker" compatibility fix to taskmgr.exe so it automatically launches non-elevated.

Reference: http://csi-windows.com/toolkit/uac-prompt-guide

---

The RunAsInvoker compatibility shim can be enabled in the registry, without needing the Application Compatibility Toolkit or even installation of an SDB.  Here is a registry script to do so (adjust the path as appropriate for your system):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers]
"C:\\Windows\\System32\\taskmgr.exe"="RunAsInvoker"
```

Comment: The environment variable definitely worked, but is awkward.  Looks like Compatibility Administrator requires running Setup for the Windows Assessment and Deployment Kit, but you can select to install only the Application Compatibility Toolkit.

Comment: Unfortunately using Compatibility Administrator does NOT work, Task Manager crashes saying "The requested operation requires elevation."

Comment: Not sure if you're still trying on 8 or 8.1, but on 8.1 the Compatibility Administrator method is working for me, with only the "RunAsInvoker" fix applied.

Curiously though, the non-elevated task manager is able to kill elevated processes without triggering an elevation prompt... that doesn't seem quite right.

Comment: You have rights to other processes whose primary token lists the same user....   Anyway, the registry activation of the RunAsInvoker shim is working fine, don't know why the .SDB approach failed so miserably.  Mind if I edit the registry script into your answer?

Comment: And my test was Windows 8.1 Professional x64, using "Compatibility Administrator (64-bit)"

Comment: Sure, feel free to add it to the answer.

Comment: The registry modification works perfectly on Win 8.1 Professional x64, thanks!

Comment: In Windows 10, this doesn't seem to work for the Task Manager in particular, but works as [a general solution for other applications](http://superuser.com/a/1122799/45163).

Answer (score 1):

I don't have Windows loaded atm., but if the Task Manager is still called **taskmgr.exe** could you create a shortcut for it and see if Properties, Shortcut, Advanced has the checkbox for "Run as administrator"? Unchecking this will allow it to start non-elevated, without actually changing any setting/policy, right?

P.S.
A nice alternative is @ technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx (Process Explorer)

Comment: Shortcut properties only apply to launching through the shortcut.  So, not right.

Comment: Also, the elevation occurs as a result of an embedded resource of type `RT_MANIFEST`.  The manifest contains `requestedExecutionLevel` of `highestAvailable` and `autoElevate` of `true`.