# Run application without administration rights in windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, administrator, uac

I followed many guides ([link1](https://superuser.com/questions/171917/force-a-program-to-run-without-administrator-privileges-or-uac/450503#450503) [link2](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/655967-allowing-user-to-run-a-program-without-admin-password)) trying to start an application that requires administration rights (such as defraggler) as a normal user (non admin), but i had no luck. Do you know if these methods are deprecated in the latest versions of windows (7, 8, 8.1 and so on)? Any other workaroud?

Thanks in advance Best regards

Comment: You can't right click it and click "run as administrator"?

Comment: I need tu run an application that needs admin rights as a non-adrmin user, so the opposite of what you're saying :)

Comment: So in other words, you want us to hack for you?

Comment: did you look at the links i posted? does it looks like hacking to you?