# How to run Chromium Edge as non admin?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, administrator, chromium, microsoft-edge

Is there any way to hide the popup?

How to run only Chromium Edge as non admin ?

Without

- Lowering your UAC settings to second notch from the bottom
- Creating a Standard Account on computer and run browsers from there

Tried [this](https://superuser.com/questions/171917/force-a-program-to-run-without-administrator-privileges-or-uac#622287) also.

[image]

Comment: You can't, without "Creating a Standard Account on computer"

Comment: If it is a standard account then why is running in admin mode?

Comment: Is there any way to hide the popup?

Comment: {shrug} Chromium Edge is  beta software.

Comment: But why [this](https://superuser.com/questions/171917/force-a-program-to-run-without-administrator-privileges-or-uac#622287) also fails

Comment: It's beta software so all bets are off.

Comment: Unless something is wrong with UAC, it does just that – by default! Unless you explicitly start software with administrator rights, it starts non-elevated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type into the url  `edge://flags#edge-de-elevate-on-launch` and enable the option that it highlights.